# flot - axis labels - monthNames wrongly ordered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, flot

In Flot is there something weird about how xaxis.monthNames behaves when the data spans a year-end ?

I have 12 months of data, starting June 2012, and I have prepared an array of 12 strings which reflect the months .

When the graph is rendered the data is correctly shown but the date labels are incorrect - they are perhaps in date order rather than the order they are in the array (or that may be coincidence).

The values and label graphs look like this :

[image]

And the resulting graph looks like this :

[image]

And finally ... the js* which uses that data looks like this :

```
var data1 = [
    {label: "Incidents", data: arrFakeData, points: {symbol: "circle", fillColor: "#058DC7"}, color: '#058DC7'},
];

p = $.plot($("#placeholder"), data1, {
    xaxis: {
        min: (new Date(2012, 6, 1)).getTime(),
        max: (new Date(2013, 5, 1)).getTime(),
        mode: "time",
        tickSize: [1, "month"],
        monthNames: arrMonthLabels,
        tickLength: 0,
        axisLabel: 'Month',
        axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
        axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
        axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
        axisLabelPadding: 5
    },
    yaxis: {
        axisLabel: 'Number of Incidents',
        axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
        axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
        axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
        axisLabelPadding: 5
    },
    series: {
        lines: {show: true},
        points: {
            radius: 3,
            show: true,
            fill: true
        },
    },
    grid: {
        hoverable: true,
        borderWidth: 1
    },
    legend: {
        labelBoxBorderColor: "none",
        position: "right"
    }
});
```

Is there something else I should be doing to get correct ordering of the x-axis labels when the dates span a calendar year ?

---

- The js is borrowed and lightly adapted from the useful blog post : http://www.pikemere.co.uk/blog/flot-how-to-create-line-graphs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The monthNames array isn't supposed to correspond in size or order to your data; it should contain 12 month names ordered from January to December.  The time plugin then picks the correct one for a particular date.

Your plot is incorrect because 1341057600000 (which is actually July, not June) causes it to pick the 7th item in the monthNames array, which in the one that you provided is "Jan" rather than "Jul".

You just need to re-order your monthNames to go from Jan to Dec.

Comment: Thank you very much - I had carefully sorted the labels to match the data ! It's all working now.